# Getting error(!bootstrap.error.title.start.failed!) when trying to open android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My android studio was getting updated..(some plugins,not sure) and my computer got restarted.
Then I updated my android studio again but when it was getting installed it showed as some corrupted files... It didn't get properly updated.

I deleted the files in AppData>Roming>Google
Also did changes in idea.property (added disable.android.first.run=true)

```
 !bootstrap.error.title.start.failed!
!bootstrap.error.message.internal.error.please.refer.to.0!https://code.google.com/p/android/issues!

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$1(MainRunner.java:41)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Layout
    at com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 2 more

-----
!bootstrap.error.message.jre.details!11.0.11+9-b60-7590822 amd64 (Oracle Corporation)
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre!
```

Answer (score 0):

delete

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
```

and rename

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
```

to

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: I uninstalled Android Atudio and deleted all the files. Then I reinstalled it. It worked